# QGIS Adding single arrow to polyline with dynamic position

Tags: qgis, style, markers

In QGIS, is it possible to add a single arrow (indicating direction) to a polyline  with a dynamic position, so that it is always in view as long as the polygon is in view?

Adding "Arrow" to a line either produces arrows at each vertex (checked repeat arrow on each segment) or does not follow the curvature of the polyline (unchecked repeat arrow on each segment)

Comment: Can you provide a diagram or image to better describe the problem? You keep switching between polyline and polygon so your question is unclear.

Comment: Sorry that should be polyline (but could also be useful with polygon)

Answer (score 3):

Not perfectly, but using a marker line set to central point will follow the visible line unless it is really near the edge.

So:

[image]

Shows as:

[image]

And zoomed in it follows:

[image]